# JAVA: Server-Client program getting NumberFormatException reading a text file

Tags: java, networking

I am working on a Server-Client program where server send Book information from a text file to the client. I'm having run time NumberFormatException error on Server class. The codes I have for this:

### **Server.java**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class UDPServer {

    private static ArrayList<ReadingMatter> books;

    private static String stringUnderQuotes(String s)
    {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\"([^\"]*)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            return m.group(1);
        }

        return null;
    }

    private static void getdata() throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ReadingMatterialInputFile.txt"));
        try {
            String category;
            while ((category = br.readLine()) != null) {

                String title = stringUnderQuotes(br.readLine());
                String ISBN = stringUnderQuotes(br.readLine());
                double price = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine().split(" ")[1]);

                ReadingMatter rm;

                if(category.equals("BOOK"))
                {
                    String author[] = stringUnderQuotes(br.readLine()).split(",");
                    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Collections.addAll(a, author);

                    rm = new Book(title, ISBN, price, a);
                }
                else if(category.equals("MAGAZINE"))
                {
                    String editor = br.readLine();

                    rm = new Magazine(title, ISBN, price, editor);
                }
                else if(category.equals("TEXTBOOK"))
                {
                    String[] author = br.readLine().split(",");
                    boolean answers = Boolean.valueOf(br.readLine().split(" ")[1]);

                    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Collections.addAll(a, author);

                    rm = new TextBook(title, ISBN, price, a, answers);
                }
                else
                {
                    String[] author = br.readLine().split(",");
                    String[] characters = br.readLine().split(",");

                    ArrayList<String> a = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Collections.addAll(a, author);

                    ArrayList<String> ch = new ArrayList<String>();
                    Collections.addAll(ch, characters);

                    rm = new Novel(title, ISBN, price, a, ch);

                }

                books.add(rm);
            }
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }

    private static String find(String category, String title)
    {
        Iterator<ReadingMatter> itr = books.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            ReadingMatter element = itr.next();

            if(element.getTitle().equals(title))
            {
                if(category.equals("BOOK") && element instanceof Book)
                {
                    return element.toString();
                }
                else if(category.equals("MAGAZINE") && element instanceof Magazine)
                {
                    return element.toString();
                }
                else if(category.equals("TEXTBOOK") && element instanceof TextBook)
                {
                    return element.toString();
                }
                else if(category.equals("NOVEL") && element instanceof Novel)
                {
                    return element.toString();
                }

            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        books = new ArrayList<ReadingMatter>();

        getdata();

        try
        {
            DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9000);

            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

            while(true)
            {

                receiveData = new byte[1024];

                DatagramPacket receivePacket =
                new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

                System.out.println ("Waiting for datagram packet");

                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);

                String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());

                String[] data = sentence.split(",");

                String category = data[0].trim();
                String title = data[1].trim();

                System.out.println("Received data: \n");
                System.out.println("Category: "+category);
                System.out.println("Title: "+title);

                String result = null;
                if(category == "" || title == "")
                {
                    result = "Category or Title data are not valid !!";
                }
                else
                {
                    result = find(category, title);

                    if(result == null)
                    result = "Sorry !! Data Not found";

                }

                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                int port = receivePacket.getPort();

                System.out.println ("\nReturning Query Result to client: \n\n"+result);



                sendData = result.getBytes();

                DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress,
                port);

                serverSocket.send(sendPacket);

            }

        }
        catch (SocketException ex) {
            System.out.println("UDP Port 9000 is occupied.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

    }
}
```

There are other classes for book category such as Book, Magazine, Novel etc.

And the text file it's reading info from is like:

```
BOOK
TITLE: "A Concise History of Australia"
ISBN: "9780521601016"
PRICE: 29.99
AUTHOR: "Stuart Macintyre"

BOOK
TITLE: "The Bloxworth Blue"
ISBN: "9780060213435"
PRICE: 12.95
AUTHOR: "William Corlett"
```

Now I'm having this error when I run Server:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""9780060213435""
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at UDPServer.getdata(UDPServer.java:37)
    at UDPServer.main(UDPServer.java:122)
```

Can I get some help to locate where I'm doing wrong? Thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

Your error message literally says it all. You are trying to format the literal `"9780060213435"` with the quotes around it. You can't have quotes around it. Remove the quotes, then do your formatting.

Comment: Why it's not catching TITLE as well?

Comment: @BlueDwarf Because you aren't parsing it, since it's a `String`

Comment: it's catching error on the second entry of the list of books as the ISBN number given is the second book, so meaning it's reading the first book ISBN without any error? any idea?

Comment: @BlueDwarf Attach a debugger and walk through the code line by line to see what's different.

Comment: @BlueDwarf You're problem is the empty line between the blocks. Since you're not skipping it, it will be read in the while loop `while ((category = br.readLine()) != null)` during the second iteration. That means the line `String title = stringUnderQuotes(br.readLine());` will then read *"BOOK"* instead of *"TITLE: "The Bloxworth Blue""*. That is why you're reading the ISBN as the price and then you're trying to parse it. Since the ISBN has enclosed quotes, it fails.

Comment: @Tom Thank you so much for pointing out the problem, yes this is the reason for giving this error.

Comment: @BlueDwarf Well, either remove these empty lines, or add an additional `br.readLine()` right at the end of your `while` loop.

Comment: Never mind, I got it working : ), added: `if ( category.trim().length() == 0 ) { continue;  }`, thanks so much again @Tom for pointing out though

Answer (score -1):

replace line number 37 by :

```
String number = br.readLine().split(" ")[1];
number = number.substring(1, number.length() - 1);
double price = Double.parseDouble(number );
```

Comment: Replace this line? 
ReadingMatter rm; (this is line no 37)

Comment: Not 37, my bad, this one : double price = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine().split(" ")[1]);

Comment: But error is with String ISBN? anyway, replacing gives this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1